# If we find a basis for a set $V$, then can we conclude that $V$ is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a set of vectors that satisfy some property.

We are firstly asked to show that $V$ is a subspace, and then asked to show what the basis for $V$ is.

But technically, if $V$ has a basis of $n$ vectors, that means that these $n$ vectors $span$ $V$, and thusly are linear indepdent.

This automatically means that the $0$ vector is in $V$, it also means that any addition or scalar multiplication of vectors in $V$, are also in $V$.

Therefore, $V$ is a subspace.

Is there any faulty logic here?

Does $(\text{$V$ having a basis $\to$ $V$ is a subspace})$?

So if a question asks me to prove its a subspace, and show its basis, then it would be fine to just show the basis?

Comment: A basis is a thing that's only defined for vector spaces, so in order to say "basis" you must be working with a vector space

Comment: $V$ is a set of vectors that live where? If they ask you to show a basis for $V$, probably the set of vectors given is in fact, not a basis for $V$. Can you try to be a little bit more precise in your question?

Comment: Yes, there's a faulty logic. You're implicitly supposing that being a basis is the same as being a subspace. With this logic, if $e_1=(1,0)$, $e_2=(0,1)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^2$, this would mean the plane f $\mathbf R^2$ *is* the set of two vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that $V$ is a subspace, then a basis would be any linearly independent spanning set. You already know this.

If you don't know yet that $V$ is a subspace, then how exactly do you find a basis? You can show that a set of vectors is linearly independent, but to show that it spans $V$, and nothing more than $V$, you basically have to show that $V$ is a subspace.

More particularly, if your putative basis is $\mathcal{B}$, showing that $V\subset\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{B})$ might be straightforward, but to show that $\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{B})\subset V$, you have to show that $V$ contains all linear combinations of vectors in $\mathcal{B}$, which is the same work you have to do to show that $V$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell that $V$ has a basis before you have proved that $V$ is a vector space, since the concept of basis assumes that we are working on a vector space.